# How to restrict string parameter to some keyof alue

Tags: typescript

I'am working with the `Array.some` function in TypeScript. I need to restrict the possible strings I will receive as the keys of some Object.

Form example I have an array with some names of the object's properties and my object implements an interface:

```js
    const props = ["a", "b", "c"]

    interface A {
        a: any,
        b: any,
        c: any
    }
```

Then I call the **some** function

```
    props.some( (prop) => {
        // ...
    })
```

I tried with:

```
    props.some( (prop: keyof A) => {
        // ...
    })
```

But I received "Type string is not assignable to type keyof A"

How is this usually resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining the array, define it `as const` so its typed as a tuple, whose members are all keys of A, so that it doesn't get automatically widened to `string[]`:

```
const props = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
```

Then

```
props.some( (prop) => {
```

will have `prop` be typed as `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`.